# Access a linux user's public_html from a WHM user's account

Tags: git, apache, vhosts, whm

I've got a user that I've set up on my server as the owner of all my git repos. I did this through ssh, so there's no WHM acct set up for that user.  I named this user 'git'.

On my primary domain, exmaple.com, I've created a subdomain called git.example.com.

I want this subdomain, which points to /home/example/subdomains/git, to instead point to /home/git/public_html.

Why would I want to do that? Well, I'm building a web interface for my git repos on my server, and I figured it would be useful to stick the interface in 'git''s public_html directory so I dont have to bother with permissions when I'm reading/writing to the repos via the interface.

(Maybe there's a better way to do this that doesn't require me to mess with permissions? idk.)

---

I started by creating a vhost include here:
/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/example/git.example.com/config.conf
and in this file I added `DocumentRoot /home/git/public_html`
and I ran `/scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --all-users` to roll my .conf into httpd.conf.

And of course, I now get a 403 when I try to go to git.example.com because I can't access user 'git''s public_html directory.

---

What do I need to add to my config.conf so that I'm able to access user 'git''s public_html?

---

**UPDATE:** I've tried a few things to get this working and none have allowed me to access the subdomain without a 403 error:

- A colleague suggested `chgrp -R nobody /home/git/public_html` but this didn't work.
- I tried adding user 'git' to group 'nobody' which didn't work, and adding user 'nobody' to group 'git' which didn't work either. (nobody is the user/group that apache uses)
- I tried adding setting the user/group for my vhost with SuexecUserGroup and RUidGid from inside my vhost include but this didn't work either. (In addition to git git, I tried git nobody, nobody nobody, and nobody git for these but no luck.)

  > ```
  > <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
  >     <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
  >         SuexecUserGroup git git
  >     </IfModule>
  > </IfModule>
  > <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
  >     RUidGid git git
  > </IfModule>
  > ```
- My webhost suggested that I backup all of my 'git' user's data, wipe the account, and then create 'git' with WHM instead of `useradd` via ssh, then restore my backup.  It's looking like this is the only option I've got.